# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Count and Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is my query. Primary Key is ID. FISID is not primary key.

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET QUANTITY = (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM table2 AS L 
   INNER JOIN table1 AS K ON K.ID=L.table1ID AND K.FISID=L.FISID 
   group by K.FISID
)
```

I have an two table on SQL Server. I want to count the relevant rows in the table2 table and write the number in the QUANTITY field.

This is my subquery result;

```
|table2 Count |
| ----------- |
|      1      |
|      1      |
|      4      |
|      2      |
|      5      |
--------------------
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, what about it don't you understand, or the 100's of other questions with the same error in it?

Comment: Please do a search in this site for `subquery return more than 1 value` and you will get 57 pages of result.

Comment: @Squirrel Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run the subquery and observed the results contain 5 rows.

Your update statement is trying to set the field `QUANTITY` to 5 different values, which it cannot do (how does it know which one of the 5 to use?!).

It looks like you want to set the `QUANTITY` to be the count of records in `table2` where there's a matching `table1ID`.

If so, here's one approach:

```sql
WITH table2_summary AS (
  SELECT table1ID
       , Count(*) AS calculated_quantity
  FROM   table2
  GROUP
      BY table1ID
)
UPDATE table1
SET    QUANTITY = table2_summary.calculated_quantity
FROM   table1
 INNER
  JOIN table2_summary
    ON table2_summary.table1ID = table1.ID
;
```

Tip: always start by writing a `SELECT` statement that shows the results you want. This can then be easily morphed in to an equivalent `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thank you. You are really saved my life. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the table with the way you are trying. Try the below SQL to update it.

```
WITH TempCTE AS (
SELECT t1.FISID AS FISID,COUNT(1) AS [totalCount] FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.ID=t2.table1ID 
  AND t1.FISID=t2.FISID
Group BY t1.FISID
)
UPDATE t1 SET t1.QUANTITY = tcte.totalCount from table1 t1
JOIN TempCTE tcte
  ON t1.FISID = tcte.FISID
```